# jenkins yaml Jcasc triggers and poll scm to add jobs automatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli, jenkins-job-dsl, jcasc

I have the following jenkins yaml which works and puts in the jobs automatically. it wont add the credentials unless I go into UI and select the same ID "github" or allow me add polling or triggering

I have tried a number of combinations that either crash the deploy or don not add the jobs at all.

```
triggers {
    pollSCM 'H/10 * * * *'
}

triggers {
    cron (H/10 * * * *)
}
```

I would like to add cron and poll scm as once job is run manually its picked up from the repo jenkinsfile

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: "Jenkins: configured automatically with JCasC plugin\n\n"
tool:
  git:
    installations:
    - home: "git"
      name: "Default"
jobs:
  - script: >
      pipelineJob('my_pipleline_build') {
          definition {
              cpsScm {
                  scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
                  scm {
                    git {
                        remote { url 'https://github.com/my_pipleline_build.git' }
                        branch '*/master'
                        credentials: ('github')
                        extensions {}
                    }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
  - script: >
      pipelineJob('my_other_pipleline_build') {
          definition {
              cpsScm {
                  scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
                  scm {
                    git {
                        remote { url 'https://github.com/cloud/my_other_pipleline_build.git' }
                        branch '*/my_pipleline_build'
                        credentials: ('github')
                        extensions {}
                    }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve using below,

```
- script: >
  pipelineJob('my_other_pipleline_build') {
      definition {
          cpsScm {
              scriptPath 'Jenkinsfile'
              scm {
                git {
                    remote { url 'https://github.com/cloud/my_other_pipleline_build.git' 
                    credentials('github')
                    }
                    branch '*/my_pipleline_build'
                    extensions {}
                }
                triggers {
                    cron("H 12 * * 6")
                }
              }
          }
      }
  }
```